# Prove that a sequence is not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I need help proving that the following sequence is not   Cauchy:
$$
\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \right)_{n=1}^\infty
$$ 
Prove that for $m,n \ge N(\varepsilon)$ the inequality criteria holds by deriving the suitable value of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hint: the sequence does not converge!

Comment: But how to prove that is not a Cauchy sequence

Comment: Well, every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is a convergent sequence. Thus, if a sequence does not converge, it cannot be Cauchy!

Comment: Can you prove it

Comment: I'm a undergraduate students so I don't know much about that so please help me out.

Comment: @Canardini 's answer proves that the sequence is not convergent and also that it is not Cauchy so you are pretty much done.

Comment: How to solve it by choosing an epsilon?

Comment: A sequence is Cauchy if for every $\varepsilon >0$ the Cauchy criterion holds. Hence, if you can find at least one $\varepsilon >0$ such that the Cauchy criterion does not hold, the sequence is not Cauchy!

Comment: @rohan I rolled back your edit which changed $\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. Although it is true that we can logically identify the series with the sequence of partial sums, the question seems clearer when the sequence of partial sums is written explicitly as in the OP prior to your edit.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 4):

let $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}$, let $n\geq1$

$u_{2n}-u_{n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{\frac{1}{k}}\geq\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{\frac{1}{2n}}=n\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally apply the Cauchy convergence definition with $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: But with epsilon equal to half doesn't hold Cauchy criteria.. Please elaborate more and help me

Comment: $u_k$ is Cauchy if $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ $\forall p,q \geq N$ $|u_p-u_q|<\epsilon$.

So , $u_k$ is not Cauchy $\exists  \epsilon>0$, $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists p,q \geq N$ $|u_p-u_q|\geq \epsilon$.

If I choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, $N=n$, $p=2n$ and $q=n$, using my answer, you can conclude

Is it clear ?

Comment: Can you please give me the full solution of that question? I got confused sorry

Comment: My answer plus the comment above is complete

Comment: I'm not much familiar with those topic so I don't understand  ..anyways thankyou so much for ya help

Comment: I am just applying the defintion of Cauchy sequence, which is also what your question is about. 
You can accept my answer .

Comment: Okay thank you so much